# sqlplus command is not working in unix server

Tags: unix, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am trying to connect to sql developer from unix server but when I use sqlplus command , it says command not found.

Should I configure aything before using the command? I am hoping to use a simple command to display the result of query ( eg: select * from dual;) in unix server.
Please help.

Comment: which command is that? If you are trying to run sqlplus iteself, you might need to first cd into $ORACLE_HOME/bin and then try again

Comment: You need to set path for variables. Check this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195524/sqlplus-command-not-found)

Comment: I am trying display the result of a query in unix server. But the query runs in sql developer.

Comment: check what the $ORACLE_HOME variable is set to and whether the path is correct. Then run `cd $ORACLE_HOME\bin  and try running your command again

Comment: Do you have Oracle client software (full client, instant client), or the  Oracle server software, installed on the Unix server? What does 'connect to SQL Developer' mean - that's another client, maybe you meant to connect to a database?

Comment: SQL Developer is a client program. sql*plus is a client program. Both can be used to connect to an oracle database when properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Check $ORACLE_BASE and $ORACLE_HOME environmental variables by runnning the following:

> echo ORACLE_BASE
>
> echo ORACLE_HOME

if they are incorrect, then set the correct values.

if $ORACLE_HOME is set correctly, run

> cd $ORACLE_HOME\bin

then run your command